# Ubuntu 22.04.4 TLS audio output not working TRIED EVERYTHING! (dummy audio)

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, hda-intel

Sound driver/card ISSUE on Ubuntu 22.04.4 TLS!
I recently got a chromebook which I install Linux on. The Chromebook is a [HP x360 Chromebook 14b](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c07729508) and I keep having a problem where it says dummy output on the audio section. I tried every single thing and most of the time it only shows up HDMI as internal audio which is HDA Intel PCH and I can't get any output for the speakers. I tried PulseAudio I tried:
this is my Hardware devices:

```
 **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and I also tried reloading the sound drivers using also and I also tried `sudo apt purge timidity-daemon` BUT STILL  NOTHING!